# Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

Scenario: I have a textbox and below that there will be a list of data. When I type something in the textbox, the list gets filtered by the text inside the textbox.

Code:

Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(xxxs: IXxx[], searchInput: string): IXxx[] {
    if (!xxxs) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchInput) {
      return xxxs;
    }
    searchInput = searchInput.toLowerCase();

    return xxxs.filter(xxx => {
      let firstName = xxx.employee.firstName.toLowerCase();
      let lastName = xxx.employee.lastName.toLowerCase();

      return firstName.includes(searchInput) &&
        firstName.startsWith(searchInput[0]) ||
        lastName.includes(searchInput) &&
        lastName.startsWith(searchInput[0]);
    });
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search person"
    [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
...
<section * ngFor="let shift of shifts | search: searchText; let last = last">
    ...
</section>
<div * ngIf="searchText && (shifts | search: searchText).length === 0" class="no-content">
    No Shifts</div>
```

This code works in all browsers except in IE and Edge.
added polyfills for `includes` and `startsWith` but still showing error.

Error:

[image]

Update #1:

I tried consoling searchText, default value is set to empty string (i.e. ''), and when I types something it shows in the console. When using debugger, i'm not getting this error. weird.

Comment: Implementing such a pipe is a bad idea anyway. Read https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `includes()` try once with `indexOf()` method.
And for `startswith()` see polyfill here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill